# joyentOS libcurl with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, passenger

Im running

```
passenger start
```

in my rails directory but i get this error:

```
 Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
```

yet if i test it

```
curl-config --feature    
SSL
IPv6
libz
IDN
NTLM
```

Im running joyents smartos am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Rails, but the curl headers are probably in /opt/local/include.  Does rails know to look there?